# easy to understand book in how to manage windows servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need a book for totally beginners in how to manage windows servers. I need a book which I can learn easily how manage windows servers. It is better if it is for windows servers 2008. I mean how to manage a real web server, for example if I take a windows dedicated server from a hosting comapny then I will easily know how to manage it.

Comment: There is no "easily know how to manage it".  Especially for a beginner. Sorry.

Comment: It it was that easy to learn from a book most of us would be unemployed.

Comment: Candle, I appreciate you're trying to broaden your knowledge but I think you'll do better either looking through old questions here, or just grabbing some beginners books from Barnes and Noble or something.  This is a Q & A site dedicated to people who are professionals and generally have *some* proficiency in the field.

Comment: @Holocryptic: I see nothing on the about page that would lead me to believe beginner questions are unwelcome.

Comment: @James You're right.  Beginner questions are fine here.  But you'll also notice that I said he should look through the old questions as well.  Search "windows books" and you'll have a plethora of questions that have been answered already.  The problem with *this* particular question is what is easy?  Something easy for you may not be easy for him.  Never mind he wants to know how to manage a web server, which covers everything from the OS, to firewalls, to TCP/IP, etc.  Much too broad based, which *is* the kind of questions we don't want here.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, I had read several books on Windows 2000 servers, but they were all pretty poor for various reasons.  What finally helped me really understand Windows 2000 servers and domain environments was the MCSA self-paced study books.  I went through all the core requirements even though I never intended on taking the tests.

I image you'll want something a little more updated and relevant for Windows Server 2008 R2, so giving you the ISBN of these book, which I still have on my bookshelf here in my office, will not do you much good.

You could start with this [free ebook,](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/training/windowsserver.aspx#offers), just look on that page for the free e-book offer, not the free e-clinic offer.

For updated materials, **I would probably start with [this package](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Book.aspx?ID=11759&locale=en-us).**  Go through these and do the practice tests, which should give a solid start to learning more on your own.  BTW: it's [much cheaper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735625085) on Amazon.

Or if you want to buy more books, check out the certification options [here](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-overview.aspx).  The site is abysmal to navigate, but if you find a test that looks to be over something you want to learn, click on the "Preparation Materials" tab and get the book that pertains to that exam.  Again, just to clarify, I'm not saying you need to take the exams and get certified (unless you also want to do that), I'm just saying the books are excellent learning materials for working with Windows Server apart from taking the exams.